# Enchantments vs Instants in Combat Phase

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I had a [Raid Bombardment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRaid%20Bombardment%5d). And I swung with a 1/1 creature, say [Goblin Bushwhacker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGoblin%20Bushwhacker%5d). 
Say I wait for the defender to declare blockers, and then use a pump spell, say [Brute Force](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrute%20Force%5d)? Would [Raid Bombardment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRaid%20Bombardment%5d) still trigger? Or would [Goblin Bushwhacker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGoblin%20Bushwhacker%5d) no longer fulfil the requirement for a less than 2 creature?

Comment: This are a lot of different questions, most (all?) which already have an answer. 

Briefly: 1) You declare you want to attack. 2) You declare attackers. 3) Defender declares defenders. (which can be no defenders at all). 4) At this stage you can still pump your creatures. 5) Combat occurs. This works even if no defenders are declared.

Comment: That was one question answered. As for the others please edit your question. Make then three separate questions. And check the site if they have been answered before.

Comment: Related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/31891/do-instants-active-before-combat-damage-is-dealt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your creature had a power 2 or less when it attacked it doesn't matter what happens to it after that.

From the Gatherer Rulings for [Raid Bombardment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRaid%20Bombardment%5d):

> The power of the attacking creature is checked only when the ability triggers. Once it triggers, Raid Bombardment will deal 1 damage to the defending player even if the creature’s power changes before the ability resolves.

Also, Raid Bombardment triggers during the Declare Attackers step, and will resolve before your opponent gets a chance to declare blockers.